# Small object detection preprocessing

Tags: computer-vision, preprocessing, object-detection

I am currently working on an object detection project in which I amtrying to detect very small objects 50x50 object in a 2k image.

EfficientDet produced a very low result if I just put the raw annotations and start training.

So my question is: Is there any pre process technique, apart from augmentation, that would help improving the model?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with a similar problem myself.

Could you please provide details about:

- What version of efficientDet you are using
- What preprocessing you are currently using on the images

One solution is to divide the images into smaller images. At this years Nvidia GTC conference, ConservationAI did a talk where they mentioned that they split up 8k images to a desired resolution. The talk can be found on the [GTC website](https://gtc21.event.nvidia.com/media/Where%20Conservation%20Meets%20AI%20Enabled%20Vision%20%5BE32301%5D/1_9ig7p3am). The relevant part is at about 30:42